# change background of tab before and after select

Tags: html, css

i've created some tab with html and css

My code link: https://codepen.io/tisaigon/pen/MWxLJYd

html

```
<!-- Navigation for the tabs -->
<div>
  <a href="#" class="tablink" data-tab="Tab1">All Dashboard |</a>
   <a href="#" class="tablink" data-tab="Tab2">Dashboard of Garage | </a>
  <a href="#" class="tablink" data-tab="Tab3">Dashboard of Vendor |</a>
   <a href="#" class="tablink" data-tab="Tab4">Dashboard of Marketing | </a>
  <a href="#" class="tablink" data-tab="Tab5">Dashboard of Sales |</a>
  <a href="#" class="tablink" data-tab="Tab6">Dashboard of Accountant |</a>
</div>
```

and css:

```
<style>
#tablink selected {
    background: #FFA500;
    color: #FFA500;
}
#tablink {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 0 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
#tablink li {
    display: gray;
    float: left;
    background: gray;
}
#tablink a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 17px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#tablink a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: #FFA500;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#tablink a:active {
    background: #FFA500;
    color:black;
}

</style>
```

But i can not add color into background of tab before and after select

Please help

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made few mistakes here,

1. tablink is a class not a ID. in CSS this is how to catch the HTML class in CSS.
   .tablink  - find a class/represent a class in CSS
   #tablink  - find a ID/represent a ID in CSS
2. In Codepen you don't need to add  tag.

Check this modified code,

```
#tablink selected {
    background: #FFA500;
    color: #FFA500;
}
#tablink {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 0 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
#tablink li {
    display: gray;
    float: left;
    background: gray;
}
a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 5px 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: #FFA500;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:active {
    background: #FFA500;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the main issue here is the identifier -

for class we use `.nameofclass`

for id we use `#nameofid`

Kindly implement these changes.